# push pull in asp.net core 6 without timer and signalr

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

helli guys .
My project is on asp.net core 6 .
I want to have push => send request from back to front , and without any timer and SignalR and ajax .
Could someone help me ?

i tried signalr , but mad my system slow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: now I don't have any code , because i want to know about the technology

Comment: have you tried with RabbitMq?

Comment: why should i use rabbitmq?